# Azcopy from a SAS url giving errors

Tags: azure-blob-storage, cloud-storage, signatures, azcopy

I am trying to copy from a SAS url location to a destination storage account. I tried the following commands but it getting few errors:

> AzCopy.exe /Source:http://wwwwww.blob.core.windows.net/vhd1/?sv=2014-02-14&sr=c&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&st=2015-08-05T04%3A00%3A00Z&se=2015-09-01T04%3A00%3A00Z&sp=rl /Dest:https://yyyyyyyy.blob.core.windows.net/vhds /Destkey:zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz filename1.vhd /Y
>
> The syntax of the command is incorrect. Invalid SAS token in parameter "Source".
>   'sr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   'sig' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   'st' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   'se' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   'sp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> AzCopy.exe /Source:http://wwwwwwww.blob.core.windows.net/vhd1 /Dest:https://xxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/vhds /SourceSAS:?sv=2014-02-14&sr=c&sig=yyyyyyyyyy&sp=rl /Destkey:zzzzzzzzz filename1.vhd /Y
>
> The syntax of the command is incorrect. Invalid SAS token in parameter "SourceSAS".
>   'sr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   'sig' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   'st' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   'se' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   'sp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I am wondering what could be the reason for these errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please surround your whole source argument with quotes, since it contains special characters to command prompt.

```
AzCopy.exe /Source:"http://wwwwww.blob.core.windows.net/vhd1/?sv=2014-02-14&sr=c&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&st=2015-08-05T04%3A00%3A00Z&se=2015-09-01T04%3A00%3A00Z&sp=rl" /Dest:https://yyyyyyyy.blob.core.windows.net/vhds /Destkey:zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz CSR316.vhd /Y
```

Comment: This worked. The other command also worked with quotes: 
AzCopy.exe /Source:http://wwwwwwww.blob.core.windows.net/vhd1 /Dest:https://xxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/vhds /SourceSAS:?"sv=2014-02-14&sr=c&sig=yyyyyyyyyy&sp=rl" /Destkey:zzzzzzzzz filename1.vhd /Y