# Trying Azcopy from a SAS url giving error

Tags: azure-storage, azcopy

I am trying to copy from a SAS url location to a destination storage account. I tried the following commands but get a few errors:

The syntax of the command is incorrect. Invalid SAS token in parameter "Source". 'sr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 'sig' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 'st' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 'se' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 'sp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

AzCopy.exe /Source:"\Users\fi\Desktop\max" /Dest:https://7a4d2ccfaea145a1bee8af7.blob.core.windows.net/ingestiondata?sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&si=IngestionSasForAzCopy5086957&sig=OQQ4kSE23NQvYOpuVHGdXggwLTM%3D&se=2020-03-101%3A48%348Z /c:Log /Y

Comment: could you please tell me your azcopy version?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to surround your whole destination argument with quotes as there are special characters in the SAS token. It will be like this,

```
AzCopy.exe /Source:"\Users\fi\Desktop\max" /Dest:"https://7a4d2ccfaea145a1bee8af7.blob.core.windows.net/ingestiondata?sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&si=IngestionSasForAzCopy5086957&sig=OQQ4kSE23NQvYOpuVHGdXggwLTM%3D&se=2020-03-101%3A48%348Z" /c:Log /Y
```

You could refer to this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196921/azcopy-from-a-sas-url-giving-errors).